# C, a derivative with eps

Tags: c, derivative, epsilon

this is a function to find a gradient from some function f.and everything works with it correctly

```
void grad(double* y,   
    double* x,    
    int n,        
    double d,    
    double (*f)(double*, int))
{ 
    double f0 = f(x, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        double save = x[i];
        x[i] += d;
        double f1 = f(x, n);
        x[i] = save;
        y[i] = (f1 - f0) / d;
    }
}
```

but then I wanted to enter the precision (eps) and converted the code a little bit. But now zeros have started to be output. What exactly am I doing wrong to achieve the desired accuracy of calculations?

```
   void grad(double* y,     
        double* x,     
        int n,        
        double d, 
        double eps;   
        double (*f)(double*, int)) { 
        double f0 = f(x, n);
        double d1, d2;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            double save = x[i];
            x[i] += d;
            double f1 = f(x, n);
            x[i] = save;
            do {
                y[i] = (f1 - f0) / d;
                  d1 = y[i];
                d = d / 10.0;
                y[i] = (f1 - f0) / d;
                 d2 = y[i];
            } while (fabs(d1 - d2) >= eps);
            
        }
    }
```

full program Before I changed it

```
void grad(double* y,    
    double* x,   
    int n,        
    double d,     
    double (*f)(double*, int)) { 
    double f0 = f(x, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        double save = x[i];
        x[i] += d;
        double f1 = f(x, n);
        x[i] = save;
        y[i] = (f1 - f0) / d;
    }
}

double f(double* x, int n) {
    int i; double sum=0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += x[i] * x[i]* x[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    int n; int i;
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    double* x;
    x = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double* y;
    y = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("x[%d] = ", i);
        scanf_s("%lf", &x[i]);
    }
    grad(y, x, n, 0.001, f);
    printf("grad f(x0,x1,..xn)\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf(" %lf ",y[i]);
    }
   // printf("grad f(1,2) = %lf i + %lf j\n", y[0], y[1]);
}
```

Comment: Time to bring out the *debugger* and step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: I don't see where you're giving `eps` a value.

Comment: @SteveSummit this is not the program itself, but only a part of it. you can "remove" the epsilon variable and set any value to 0<eps<1..

Comment: Your second function doesn't compile. And you really need to fix your formatting so that parameters are better distinguishable from local variables.

Comment: @Vs_De_S See, this is why we ask people to post complete examples.  Now you've wasted my time, and I yours.

Comment: @SteveSummit I have attached the full code

Comment: @interjay my compiler compiled this, but returned zeros instead of normal values

Comment: Your compiler might be broken because there is a `;` instead of a `,`. And the "full example" you posted is of code that you say works correctly, making it useless here.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69566402/4989451 for alternative method of computing derivatives that is resistant to small `eps`

Answer (score 1):

> What exactly am I doing wrong to achieve the desired accuracy of calculations?

**Uninitialized object**

In `fabs(d1 - d2) >= eps`, `eps` is uninitialized.

---

**Fixed offset**

`x[i] += d;` (a fixed offset)  takes the *floating* out of floating point math.

`x[i] += d` is the same as `x[i] += 0.0` when `x[i]` is much larger than `d`.

`x[i] += d` is the same as `x[i] = d` when `x[i]` is much smaller than `d`.

Both extremes demo that `x[i] += d` is not a good way to find a suitable offset for a multi-variable function slope calculation.  Easy to incur divide by 0 in later code.

---

Better: when `fabs(x[i]) > DBL_MIN`, scale instead: `x[i] *= e` where `e` is 1.0001, 1.0000000001, 1.000000000001, etc. and adjust slope code calculation accordingly.  This too does have limitations and more code to handle wee `x[i]`.

---

Even better: IMO, offset `x[i]` by N floating point numbers, where N is some modest integer.  E.g. `N==1` --> `x[i] = nextafter(x[i], x[i]*2);`.

---

Best: need more info as *best* is case dependent.

---

**FP debug tip**

> But now zeros have started to be output

Use `"%e"` or `"%g"` instead of `"%f"`.  It is more informative.  `"%f"` prints zero for about half of all `double` values.

```
// printf(" %lf ",y[i]);
// Alternatives
printf(" %e ", y[i]);
printf(" %.*e ", 16, y[i]);
printf(" %g ", y[i]);
printf(" %.*g ", 17, y[i]);
printf(" %a ", y[i]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, some special cases are not considered in my task. Therefore, we are considering something basic. Could you please edit the existing code?

Comment: @Vs_De_S Is not `x[i] *= e` the beginning of something  basic enough?

Comment: look you said I should change e. (should it be a loop?) and one more thing.I told you that I want to enter the desired eps from the keyboard, how do I do it?

Comment: One mor thing. You said **Uninitialized object**. I made eps as a function parameter. so in main I will be able to set its value. so what exactly did I do wrong?

Comment: did you suggest that? I don't understand...

`   double e= 0.001;
    int ed = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        double save = x[i];
        do {
            
            x[i] *=(ed+e);
            e = e*0.1;
        } while (fabs(x[i]) > DBL_MIN);
        
        double f1 = f(x, n);
        x[i] = save;
        y[i] = (f1 - f0) / d;
    }`